# How to calculate the sum of values in sql using only end date

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have created an application in which i want to perform a query to get the sum of values from a table using the end date instead of using start date and end date.what i want to perform is to sum all the values from the given date to the previous date.The query which i have created doesn't shows the expected output can anyone tell me how i can do it.

Table structure:

```
  //daybook label
    String CREATE_DAYBOOK = "CREATE TABLE " + DAYBOOK_DETAILS + "("
            + DAYBOOK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + DAYBOOK_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOKUSER_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_AMOUNT_IN + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_AMOUNT_OUT + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_EXTRA_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_MOBILENO + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_TIME + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DAYBOOK);
```

Query:

```
  SELECT IFNULL(SUM(otheramount),0) as amountin,IFNULL(SUM(amountout),0) as amountout FROM daybookdetails WHERE date < '" + changeddate + "' AND mobileno = '" + bfarmermobno + "'  AND daybookdescription = '" + bno + "';
```

[image]

If the date is 15-12-2016 means then it should take this date as the end date and it should sum the values from 01-11-2016 to 15-12-2016.

Comment: So the end date is 12-12-2016 but it should still sum up the values from 15-12-2016? That's weird, I don't get it. Or is 15-12-2016 exclusive?

Comment: @Rolfツ the end date is 15-12-2016 from that date it should sum of the values till the 01-11-2016

Comment: "From that date", thats totaly unclear. Normally you define a range as in 10 to 20 or januari to december, not december to november, is that really what you want?

Comment: @Rolfツ i would like to get date like this 15-12-2016 to 01-11-2016

Comment: 01-11-2016 to 15-12-2016 seems more logical to me.

Comment: @Rolfツ  yes i know it's logical but i don't know the exact start date only thing i will have is the last date then how could i do it in a  single query

Answer (score 0):

One method of looking at this, is to use a stored procedure to calculate the business code of your application. The procedure can process through the results and add up the balances and output a result set. Another benefit of a stored procedure is that updates can be done without disrupting the compiled application code. This is useful when a mobile application is using a remote database, the stored procedure can be changed/updated on the remote database without the mobile users ever knowing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `value_sums`(check_date datetime, mobileno varchar(45),    daybookdescription varchar(45))
BEGIN
declare balance float;
Declare Loop_End Boolean Default 0;

declare myAmountin float;
declare myAmountout float;
declare myDescription text;
delcare mydate text;

declare Loop_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
(SELECT date, IFNULL(SUM(otheramount),0) as amountin,IFNULL(SUM(amountout),0) as amountout 
FROM daybookdetails WHERE date < check_date AND mobileno = mobileno AND 
daybookdescription = daybookdescription);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET Loop_End=1;

open Loop_Cursor;

curloop: LOOP

    FETCH Loop_Cursor into mydate, myAmountin, myAmountout, myDescription;                      
    set balance = balance - myAmountout;
    set balance = balance + myAmountin;

    select mydate, mydescription, myAmountin, myamountout, balance;

UNTIL Loop_End END REPEAT;
CLOSE Loop_Cursor;  

END
```

To call the procedure use

```
call value_sums('2016-12-31','<mobile number>','<book_description>');
```